# How to set default view in folders in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Today I tried to figure out how to set the view of a folder the same for all. For example I want to always have full details of the containing files. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Open an Explorer window and set the view to how you want it for all folders, e.g. 'Details'.  Then go to Tools - Folder Options, select the View tab, and click the 'Apply to Folders' button.  That will set all folders to the view you selected.

Comment: In addition to this, you could set a folder template to preserver which columns show up in Details view across all folders, as detailed here: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15699-folder-template-default.html